# What purpose does the Outlook "Archive" folder serve for accounts managed only via web browsers?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, archiving

According to the official [Microsoft Support Page](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Archive-items-manually-ecf54f37-14d7-4ee3-a830-46a5c33274f6?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB), the archive feature is primarily used to split Outlook data into 2 seperate .pst files to optimise the perfomance of the Outlook desktop program.

But for those who manage their emails only through a web browser does using the archive folder have any particular benefit, or is it simple to "declutter" the inbox?

Comment: Archive feature is used to move emails off the server, so less data has to be kept on the server, or sent by the server when a complete sync is done.  What benefits you get out of archive depends on your usage habits, I have emails from 2001 on my server, and archived emails from 1991.

Comment: Ah so it prevents your *entire* email history syncing thus saving time and unnecessary data transfer, that makes sense. I'm happy to accept that as an answer if you wish to post it as such. Perhaps the person who downvoted the question wouldn't mind informing me where I went wrong too?

Comment: I will remind you that leaving a comment, when you issue a vote on a question, is not required and voting is anonymous for a reason

Comment: Of course! It's simply useful, if I made an error that was worthy of a downvote I can only fix it or avoid making it again if I know what it is - otherwise the vote doesn't seem to achieve anything